# iPhoto is rejected: These apps cannot be accepted on this computer

Tags: macos, iphoto, mac-app-store

I'm trying to install the latest version of iPhoto on OS X 10.7. In the app store the label shows "Accept". If I click on the button, i enter my Apple-ID, unfortunately this does not start the download. I do get the error message "*These apps cannot be accepted on this computer*".

Any ideas how to get rid of the error message and install iPhoto?

Comment: If you go to your *Purchases*, can you try clicking *Install* from there?

Comment: No, there's "Accept" on the button. Hitting this button drives me back to the situation described above.

Comment: Okay, that was suggested here: [Cannot reinstall iPhoto from App Store in Lion](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/43801/cannot-reinstall-iphoto-from-app-store-in-lion) — but weird that it's not the same situation for you. Where did you install iPhoto from before? Was it already installed on the Mac, maybe from another user?

Comment: This is a new MacBook Pro. I haven't bought or installed iPhoto before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "problem" is that iLife 11 ships with every recent Mac anyway. It will receive its updates through OS X *Software Update* mechanism.

The iLife 11 version of iPhoto you see in the Mac App Store uses the App Store's own update mechanism. It's sold for those who didn't get iLife 11 with their Mac.

These two are essentially the same, but since they use different update mechanisms, you can't install the App Store version when you already have the "normal" one on your Mac. In fact, the latest iPhoto version (as of today) is 9.2.3 — it's the same for the preinstalled version *and* the App Store version.

So, long story short: You don't really need to install the App Store version.

Comment: So how can i start/use iPhoto? I cannot find it in the launch pad or the Applications folder.

Comment: It wasn't on the Mac already? If I recall correctly, it should be installed under */Applications*. Do you recall ever deleting it from your hard drive? Do you have a backup from your initial Mac setup? Anyway, if it's not there, you should call Apple support — this was suggested in several forums. They will supply you with a new download code for iLife 11.

Comment: I got the download codes. But I don't know what I have to do with them. Where can I get iPhoto with this codes? If I go to the app store I end up with the initial problem.

Comment: There should be a "Redeem" link under the Top Charts.

Answer (score 1):

I just bought a Macbook Pro and I had the exact same problem. I'll refer to my Macbook as #1 and my other mac as #2 to make things a bit easier.

First, make sure that your computers are both synced to iCloud.

Here's what I did: On #1, I clicked on the apple sign and then hit software update. I updated everything I could. While it was doing that, I went over to #2 and enabled photo stream on my iCloud account.

At first that didn't work, so I went to the App Store and updated iPhoto. 
After all the updates were complete on #1, I went to the App Store there, hit the "Purchased" sign at the top and saw iPhoto with "Install" next to it.